# Why won't Pandas join DataFrames on matching datetime indexes, even though they appear identical?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes containing data from the same time period with datetime indexes: `prices` and `trendsdata`. When I click to visibly look at the datetime indexes in Spyder (see image below), the indexes appear to have many overlapping values:

[image]

However, when I attempt to join the dataframes like so, the join is unsuccessful and yields nan values:

```
test = prices.join(trendsdata)
```

[image]

Interestingly, when I manually try to compare two index values that appear identical, it appears they are not equivalent to the interpreter:

```
trendsdata.index.values[18]
Out[12]: numpy.datetime64('2020-02-18T18:00:00.000000000')

prices.index.values[0]
Out[13]: numpy.datetime64('2021-02-18T18:00:00.000000000')

prices.index.values[0] == trendsdata.index.values[18]
Out[14]: False
```

I suspect this is the root of the problem, but cannot figure out why they are not equivalent and not joining properly.

Comment: The year is different...

Comment: Good catch, thank you. Looks like I entered in '2020' to the data retrieval tool instead of '2021'.